# copy the dropdownlist selected option to text area on mvc view-- JQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to copy or put the text option selected on the dropdown list to text area Jquery on MVC View and I select by the text area doesn't show the text.. Any help??

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("LocationText", "Location Letter Text ", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("RemarksId", null, new { id = "RemarksId", @class = "form-control" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Remarks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Remarks, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Remarks", rows = 5, cols = 70 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

JQuery

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jscript">
      $(function () {
      $('#RemarksId').change(function()  {
      var str= $("#RemarksId option:selected").text();
        $('#Remarks').val(str);
      });
    });
  </script>
}
```

Comment: what scripts are in your bundle? you may need to move the jquery tag to above the bundle (or remove it completely if it is included in your bundle)

Comment: Your script urls may be wrong, could you check them ? Because your code looks correct by the way you don't need to write change function into the $(function()...)

Comment: what urls can I  use?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the value of selected option from dropdown using .text method.
please refer below code snippet

```
$(function () {
      $('#RemarksId').change(function()  {
      var str= $(this).val();
        $('#Remarks').val(str);
      });
    });
```

And, from the dropdown options
change
option value="1"
to
option id="1"

Do this for all options, and the above code will work for you.

Also see demo fiddle here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2f8m3vyk/1/)

Let me know if it works for you or not.

Thanks

Comment: actually the jquery in the question should work fine, even if it is a bit inefficient. You have changed the function to get the value rather than the text - are you sure this is what the OP wants?

Comment: According to the description of the question, it seems that he is having issue applying the logic on elements, which is based on jQuery, so I made some changes and provided snippet with demo, I thought it might help him to resolve the problem or atleast give him right direction..

Comment: No. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: can you tell me what error are you getting.. or any more info which you can provide..

Comment: No error. Only, it doesn't show the select value on the text area

Comment: have you checked the demo fiddle link I attached? can you share your updated code?

Comment: I put@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#RemarksId').change(function () {
                var str = $(this).val();
                $('#Remarks').val(str);
            });
        });
    </script>
}

Comment: Scripts { <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('#RemarksId').change(function () { var str = $(this).val(); $('#Remarks').val(str); }); }); </script> }

Comment: But still doest show the value on the text area

Comment: Do alert the variable "str" after you assign dropdown value in it.. it should alert the selected option text.. let me know what you get

Comment: It doesn't show alert that means the JavaScript section doesn't work

Comment: You need to debug it step by step.. first confirm that you are getting in the change event.. so alert some text at the first line in change event block..

Comment: More debugging: use browser's inspector tool console tab.. where you can see all of your JavaScript errors..

Comment: I am using inspector tool on the browser but it show no errors.

Comment: That means your change event does not seem correct.. to help you further.. can you share pure html snippet rendered in browser?? It might possible it does not match with the logic bind with Id selector

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8vO9uCuHtSmcWhid1E5SHJOSFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The complyte file is on that link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125942/discussion-between-niravshah-php-and-marimar).